# Circle of Points with TikZ

Tags: tikz-styles

I would like to define a series of dots distributed around a circle and be able to define the number of points using `tikz`. Is it possibile without involving `pstricks`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [draw=red, line width=2pt,dash pattern=on 5pt off 5pt] circle(5cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just use polar coordinates and a for loop to specify the angle.

Comment: Try `` \foreach\n in {0,10,20,...,360-10} {   \fill (\n:1) circle (1pt);  }``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this --replace black color with red

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \i in {0,5,10,15,20,25,30,...,360}{% 
\filldraw [black]  (\i:3cm) circle (0.4pt);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### EDIT

Circle centre defined at coord (0,0) and given the name {a}

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (0,0){a};
\foreach \i in {0,5,10,15,20,25,30,...,360}{% 
\filldraw [red]  (\i:3cm) circle (0.4pt);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

To reduce the number of dots in the circle simply reduce the number of the angles to 45--90--360 as below

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (0,0){a};
\foreach \i in {0,45,90,...,360}{% 
\filldraw [blue]  (\i:3cm) circle (1pt);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: i) It suffices to write `{0,5,...,355}`. ii) How do you control the number of points as required by the asker?

Comment: Thank you. Just one last thing: what should I do if I want to define the center of the circle?

Comment: @FlyBob please see edit

Comment: @MarianG. please reduce the angular gaps as shown in the edit above to reduce the number of dots in the circle

Answer (score 4):

Here is my proposition (with comments):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (c) at (12,3);  % center of circle
  \def\radius{6cm}            % radius of circle
  \def\nbpts{400}             % nb of points
  \def\radpt{.5pt}            % radius of points
  \colorlet{point color}{red} % color of points

  \foreach \numpt in {1,...,\nbpts}{
    \fill[point color] (c) ++ (360/\nbpts*\numpt:\radius) circle(\radpt);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]